# Last.Fm API - Invalid parameters when trying to use track.scrobble service in Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, last.fm

I have gone through the Last.Fm authentication process (as outlined [here](https://www.last.fm/api/webauth)), and that worked out just fine - got the session key back and everything. However, when I attempt to make an authenticated POST request to the track.scrobble method of the Last.Fm API, I am consistently getting a response of "Invalid parameters - Your request is missing a required parameter" (Last.FM API error #6).

I am so confused as to why this is happening as I'm virtually positive I'm including all required parameters in my track.scrobble call. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my scrobble track method:

```
  scrobbleTrack(track) {
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    let params = {
        artist: track.artist,
        track: track.title,
        duration: track.duration,
        timestamp: timestamp,
        api_key: this.apiKey,
        method: 'track.scrobble',
        sk: this.sessionKey,
    };
    const apiSig = this._createApiSig(params);
    params.api_sig = apiSig;
    params.format = 'json';
    const body = JSON.stringify(params);
    request.post(this.baseUrl, { //this.baseUrl is "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?format=json"
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: body
    }, function(err, res) {
        if(err) { return err; }
  });
```

And then here is my _createApiSig method:

```
  _createApiSig(params) {
    let apiSig = '';
    const keys = Object.keys(params).sort();
    for(let key of keys) {
        apiSig += key + params[key];
    }
    apiSig += this.secret;
    return md5(encodeURIComponent(apiSig));
  }
```

As far as I can tell, I am supplying all required parameters for track.scrobble (artist, track, api_key, api_sig, sk, timestamp).

For further reference, [here is the documentation for the API endpoint I'm trying to access](https://www.last.fm/api/show/track.scrobble).

Comment: Make sure that your params are indeed what you think they are first, and make sure that your method has the `this` you expect. Those are common mistakes I make. FYI:  You can use the chrome debug tools with node.js to check these things, or `console.log`.

Comment: My params are set to what I expect them to be - doing a console.log on params once all of them have been set show that all are properly set and to the values that I expect them to be set to... and checking the _createApiSig method, it is indeed properly creating an alphabetical by parameter name string so that one should be correct as well, I think... So I don't think that the issue is in not having these params set to the values that I expect, unless I'm overlooking something really stupid

Comment: Can you supply a dump of what params/body looks like after it was entirely generated?

Comment: @LukasBach here's what the params looks like:

{ artist: 'The Monkees',
  track: 'Daydream Believer',
  duration: 177,
  timestamp: 1531340440263,
  api_key: 'e0dc0d194eaed6dd63b7732507471214',
  method: 'track.scrobble',
  sk: 's6XgdqbLINnQpLQdrxOH6Kn1NDyCDK9r',
  api_sig: 'b64ee024e19ce8877f937eccf083f90f',
  format: 'json' }

 and here is what apiSig looks like prior to encoding:

api_keye0dc0d194eaed6dd63b7732507471214artistThe Monkeesduration177methodtrack.scrobblesks6XgdqbLINnQpLQdrxOH6Kn1NDyCDK9rtimestamp1531340440263trackDaydream Believerfe2d007371ae4ef6c2c0d2a3ce9e4bcd

Comment: `Date.now()` returns a timestamp in milliseconds since epoch, whereas the API requires a unix timestamp (i.e. *seconds* since epoch). Try dividing your `timestamp` by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

anyone that might be encountering this issue, what worked for me was using a URLsearchparam object in the body data of the request instead of JSON.stringify

basically:

```
let data = new URLSearchParams(params)
    let myReq = new Request("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    })

fetch(myReq)
```